# Powershell - get string information to a console for user from one script to another

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have 2 scripts, one serves as a **Worker** - uses variables to complete commands, second serves as a function **Library**. **Worker** via variable loads **Library** and uses functions from there.

As a user, when I run the script I would like to see the output in the console which I defined as the outcome for **Library** script.

Example **Worker** script:

```
Param(
    [string]$server_01,
    [string]$releaseDefinitionName,
    [string]$pathRelease,
    [string]$buildNumber,
    [string]$command_01,
    [string]$scheduledTask_01
    )

$pathScriptLibrary = $pathRelease + "\" + $buildNumber + "\" + "_scripts"
. $pathScriptLibrary\_library.ps1

$user = xxx
$password = xxx
$cred = xxx

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server_01 -Credential $cred -ErrorAction Stop -ScriptBlock {powershell $command_01}
```

Example **Library** script:

```
function Stop-ScheduledTasks{
    Write-Output [INFO]: Stopping scheduled tasks... -ForegroundColor White
    Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName  "$scheduledTask_01" | ForEach {
        if ($_.State -eq "Ready") {
            Write-Output [WARNING]: Scheduled task $scheduledTask_01 was already stopped. -ForegroundColor Yellow
            }
        else {
            Stop-ScheduledTask -TaskName "$scheduledTask_01"
            Write-Output [OK]: Running task $scheduledTask_01 stopped. -ForegroundColor Green
        }
    }
}

function Start-ScheduledTasks{
    Write-Output [INFO]: Starting scheduled tasks... -ForegroundColor White
    Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName  "$scheduledTask_01" | ForEach {
        if ($_.State -eq "Running") {
            Write-Output [WARNING]: Scheduled task $scheduledTask_01 already started. -ForegroundColor Yellow
            }
        else {
            Start-ScheduledTask -TaskName "$scheduledTask_01"
            Write-Output [OK]: Stopped scheduled task $scheduledTask_01 started. -ForegroundColor Green
        }
    }
}
```

**Use case:**

1. User starts the deployment by clicning the deploy button in Azure DevOps UI
2. The task using the **Worker** script takes function from **Library** script (in this case stops Scheduled Task) and performs it
3. User checks log on the Azure DevOps side and sees the custom output lines from Library script. (2 of them now - 1. starting with [INFO], 2. either starting with [WARNING] or [OK]).

Could you please advice a solution how to achieve that? Thank you.

NOTE: Those examples are run in Azure DevOps (on premise) release pipelines and desired outcomes are ment for users running those pipelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to write to the azure devops pipeline log, then you should avoid using `Write-Output`. That does something subtly different; it adds to the function's return value.

So for example the Write-Output in the function Stop-ScheduledTask; that is roughly equivalent to you putting at the end of the function:

```
return "[WARNING]: Scheduled task $scheduledTask_01 was already stopped."
```

That *might* end up being printed to the pipeline log, or it might not; and importantly, it might completely mess up a function which is genuinely trying to return a simple value.

Instead of using Write-Output, I recommend using [Write-Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host?view=powershell-7.2). What that does is immediately write a line to the pipeline log, without affecting what a library function will return.

```
Write-Output "[WARNING]: Scheduled task $scheduledTask_01 was already stopped."
```

You can also use Write-Warning and Write-Error.

Comment: The issue is not getting a custom string lines from Worker script, but how to pipe it from the Library script and then show for the user. I've replaced Desired solution in description for Use case as it should more clarify the issue.

Comment: My answer is still the same: use Write-Host.

Comment: Tried, unfortunately, same result - log output is missing. Could you please show me how to adjust worker and library script in order to show the write-host output in the console? Thank you.

Comment: I finnaly managed to get it working and changed it accordingly. Thank you!